# How to implement using LINQ or lambdas?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, boolean, expression

I am curious if the following could be implemented using a LINQ statement or a lambda. I am new to both, so I'm not quite sure how it would be coded. The intent is to have a Func<> delegate that I can add multiple callbacks to, and have them all evaluated as a boolean AND expression of all of the return values. A preferred solution would allow a single false to short circuit the rest of the evaluations. I have implemented this in a brute force manner, and the code and output looks as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestHarness
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Func<bool, bool, bool, bool> validPosition;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            validPosition += Func1;
            validPosition += Func2;
            validPosition += Func3;

            Delegate[] delegates = validPosition.GetInvocationList();

            bool composite = true;
            int i = 0;

            foreach (Func<bool, bool, bool, bool> d in delegates)
            {
                composite = composite & d(false, true, true);
                if (!composite)
                    break;
                ++i;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + composite + "\tIterations: " + i);

            composite = true;
            i = 0;
            foreach (Func<bool, bool, bool, bool> d in delegates)
            {
                composite = composite & d(true, false, true);
                if (!composite)
                    break;
                ++i;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + composite + "\tIterations: " + i);

            composite = true;
            i = 0;
            foreach (Func<bool, bool, bool, bool> d in delegates)
            {
                composite = composite & d(true, true, false);
                if (!composite)
                    break;
                ++i;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + composite + "\tIterations: " + i);

            composite = true;
            i = 0;
            foreach (Func<bool, bool, bool, bool> d in delegates)
            {
                composite = composite & d(true, true, true);
                if (!composite)
                    break;
                ++i;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + composite + "\tIterations: " + i);
        }

        bool Func1(bool a, bool b, bool c)
        {
            return a;
        }
        bool Func2(bool a, bool b, bool c)
        {
            return b;
        }
        bool Func3(bool a, bool b, bool c)
        {
            return c;
        }
    }
}

Output:

Result: False   Iterations: 0
Result: False   Iterations: 1
Result: False   Iterations: 2
Result: True    Iterations: 3
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: While this is on-topic here; you may consider going to CodeReview.SE for working code questions

Comment: I don't see any brute force there. Also do you really need these counts?

Comment: If you reduce this to simple predicates `Func<T,bool>` you can chain them by the `&&` operator and benefit of its short-circuiting character. But I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. What's the bigger picture?

Comment: _"have a Func<> delegate that I can add multiple callbacks to"_ -- this requirement seems to me to force you into the `GetInvocationList()` approach. Please explain either the requirement, or why you think even with that requirement, there might be an alternative solution. Frankly, as stated so far the question is either "unclear" or "too broad".

Comment: The end-purpose for this is in a game that will have different types of installable objects that have 1 to n criteria for whether or not it can be placed on a specific tile. The class uses composition instead of inheritance, An object of type "Wall" has only a single criteria - Is the tile empty? An installable object of type "Door" has the criteria - Is the tile empty? Are there walls to the North and South, or the East and West? When the installable object is instantiated, the 'n' number of callbacks would be added to its callback Func<> delegate that should be evaluated  as expressed above.

Comment: To answer Ivan, no, the iteration count is there just to show the short circuiting of the evaluations.

Comment: *validPosition += Func1;*: there is a problem here: `validPosition` is an instance variable... It isn't resetted. The second time you click on the button, you'll get `Func1, Func2, Func3, Func1, Func2, Func3` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally create a custom extension method and put the logic inside (most likely using a `foreach` like in your sample to avoid closures and lambda overhead). But since you are interested in LINQ solution, the [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method is exactly what you need:

*result:*

> **true** if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the specified predicate, or if the sequence is empty; otherwise, **false**

*short circuiting:*

> The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined.

Equivalent sample LINQ code:

```
var delegates = validPosition.GetInvocationList().Cast<Func<bool, bool, bool, bool>>();

Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + delegates.All(d => d(false, true, true)));
Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + delegates.All(d => d(true, false, true)));
Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + delegates.All(d => d(true, true, false)));
Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + delegates.All(d => d(true, true, true)));
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!